# How to implement read more functionality in title Using fullcalender

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need to implement `read more/read less` functionality using `jquery calendar`. I am explaining my code below.

```
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="getCalendar()">GET</button>
  <div class="calender" id='calendar'></div>
  <script>
    function getCalendar() {
      var todayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
      // var evStartDate = new Date(inputdate)
      //console.log('date',evStartDate);
      //addClassByDate(evStartDate);
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'year,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        ///////// edit
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
          //alert('day click');
        },
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent) {
          //alert('event clicked');
          $('#eventpopup').modal({
            backdrop: 'static'
          });
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element, view){
                    var evStart = moment(view.intervalStart).subtract(1, 'days');
                    var evEnd = moment(view.intervalEnd).subtract(1, 'days');
                    if (!event.start.isAfter(evStart) ||
                        event.start.isAfter(evEnd)) { return false; }
                },
        ///////////
        defaultDate: todayDate,
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [{
          title: 'jQuery is a fast and concise JavaScript Library',
          start: '2017-12-01'
        }, {
          title: 'hello',
          start: '2017-12-02'
        }, {
          id: 999,
          title: 'hii',
          start: '2017-11-02'
        }]
      });
    }
  </script>
```

Here I need if the `title` text length is more than 10 there should be one `read more` option and `.....` after those half text . When user will click on that read more option the total title will display and when user will click on `read less` option again it will show the normal text.[Here is my full plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/Am78vJhXcVTCPUilwH0h?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a tooltip using qtip this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/basic/jquery.qtip.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/basic/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
  <link href="calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="moment.js"></script>
  <script src="fullcalendar.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Calendar</h1>
  <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="getCalendar()">GET</button>
  <div class="calender" id='calendar'></div>
  <script>
    function getCalendar() {
      var todayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
      // var evStartDate = new Date(inputdate)
      //console.log('date',evStartDate);
      //addClassByDate(evStartDate);
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'year,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        ///////// edit
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
          //alert('day click');
        },
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent) {
          //alert('event clicked');
          $('#eventpopup').modal({
            backdrop: 'static'
          });
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
          var evStart = moment(view.intervalStart).subtract(1, 'days');
          var evEnd = moment(view.intervalEnd).subtract(1, 'days');
          if (!event.start.isAfter(evStart) ||
            event.start.isAfter(evEnd)) {
            return false;
          }
          if (event.title.length > 10) {
            var eventShortTitle = event.title.substring(0, 10) + '...';
            element.qtip({
              content: event.title,
              position: {
                at: 'bottom left', // at the bottom right of...
              }
            });
            element.find('.fc-title').text(eventShortTitle);
          } 
        },
        ///////////
        defaultDate: todayDate,
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [{
          title: 'jQuery is a fast and concise JavaScript Library',
          start: '2017-12-01'
        }, {
          title: 'hello',
          start: '2017-12-02'
        }, {
          id: 999,
          title: 'hii',
          start: '2017-11-02'
        }]
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: this is a good approach but I don't think it actually amends the title in the main rendered event - you define `eventShortTitle` but then never use it for anything. Did you miss a line or two of code from your solution?

Comment: @jcarrera : Ok,its working but the tooltip is not remaining constant when mousehover it. check this [plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/Am78vJhXcVTCPUilwH0h?p=preview).

Comment: The tooltip's position causes this, becouse overlaps the calendar event. I changed the tooltip's position in my answer.

Comment: @jcarrera : yes but the tooltip is showing inside another day which is totaly wrong display.

Comment: Updated again !

Comment: Yes, now its perfect. Thank you ?